# Linux "ls -Z" shows question mark for security context

Tags: linux, permissions, selinux

I've got some files that aren't being served on a site, and assuming it was a permissions issue I ran `ls -Z` but keep seeing ? in place of the security context:

```
-rw-rw-r--  pete pete ?                                index.cfm
```

I get this running `sudo` as well. Can anyone explain what the ? means or what I need to do to fix the file?

I've tried using `sudo chcon system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 index.cfm` to match the other permissions of files in the folder, but that doesn't help. Also if I try to recreate the file I get the ? again

```
cat index.cfm > index.bkp
sudo ls -Z
-rw-rw-r--  pete pete ?                                index.bkp
-rwxrwxrwx. pete pete system_u:object_r:httpd_config_t:s0 index.cfm
mv index.bkp index.cfm
-rw-rw-r--  pete pete ?                                index.cfm
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `getenforce` and `mount` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of the exclamation mark is only given in [`ls` info page](http://phpunixman.sourceforge.net/index.php/info/ls), not in its man page:

> '-Z'
> '--context'
> '--scontext'
> '--lcontext'
> '--format=context'
>
> Display the SELinux security context **or '?' if none is found**.  '-Z'
> counts as format option and enables displaying of SELinux context.
> '--scontext' prints SELinux context left to the file name.
> '--lcontext' prints long format with SELinux context in the middle.
> '--context' prints permissions, user/group, context and file name
> (in comparison to '--lcontext', omits size, modification time and
> number of hardlinks).

Thus, this means that no security context was added to the file. And the fact that it still has no security context when you re-create the file indicates that the parent directory has no security context that can be inherited from.